# Is there a way to select columns with html tags in them in MySQL?

Tags: html, mysql

I have a database where some columns have HTML tags in them, IE

```
Rot<sub>1</sub>
```

I try running queries, like

```
SELECT Rot<sub>1</sub> FROM chem.thermTable;
```

But I get an error message in my SQL syntax.  Putting the column name in quotes simply returns the column name.  Typing

```
SELECT * FROM chem.thermTable;
```

Works but returns other values I don't need as well.  I searched and haven't found any solutions.  Thanks for your help!

Edit:  I am trying to query

```
SELECT Method,Basis,Rot<sub>1</sub> from chem.thermtable;
```

Comment: Why the hell you want to put HTML tags in column name, at first place... This might bring you a lot of problems in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use back quotes around the column name like this :

```
SELECT `Rot<sub>1</sub>` FROM chem.thermTable;
```

IMHO, this a not a clean column name and you should consider renaming it.

Comment: Thanks!  That seems to have done it.  I will consider changing the column names too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for this?

```
SELECT ColumnNameX, ColumnNameY, ColumnNameZ FROM chem.thermTable;
```

Where you'd change the ColumnName X, Y, and Z to be the column names you want. If not, you should perhaps clarify your question with an example of a few rows worth of data.